# Memoize a Double function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, memoization

I have a function

```
slow :: Double -> Double
```

which gets called very often (hundreds of millions of times), but only gets called on about a thousand discrete values.  This seems like an excellent candidate for memoization, but I can't figure out how to memoize a function of a Double.

The standard technique of making a list doesn't work, since it's not an integral type.  I looked at Data.MemoCombinators, but it doesn't natively support Doubles.  There was a `bits` function for handling more data types, but `Double`  isn't an instance of `Data.Bits`.

Is there an elegant way to memoize `slow?

Comment: If you know the values it'll be called on ahead of time, you could use `Data.Map`, `fromList`, and `map`. If you don't know the values ahead of time, you need some sort of lazy data structure that represents "application of `slow` to all possible values of type `Double`". The difficulty of doing that in a sane way is why there's nothing for it in `Data.MemoCombinators` at the moment.

Comment: Compute all the values at compile time and just build a giant case statement with 1000 branches.  You won't get any more efficient than that.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez: I'd love to, but the 1000 branches aren't known until run time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always use [ugly-memo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uglymemo).  The internals are impure, but it's fast and does what you need (except if the argument is NaN).

Answer (score 3):

I think [`StableMemo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stable-memo) should do exactly what you want, but I don't have any experience with that.

---

There are two main approaches: use the `Ord` property to store the keys in a tree structure, like [`Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map-Lazy.html#t%3aMap). That doesn't require the integral property you'd need for e.g. a [`MemoTrie`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MemoTrie/0.6.1/doc/html/Data-MemoTrie.html) approach; it is thus slower but very simple.

The alternative, that works with yet much more general types, is to map unorderedly onto a large integral domain with a [Hash function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hashable/latest/doc/html/Data-Hashable.html#g:2), in order to, well, store the keys in a [hash map](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unordered-containers/latest/doc/html/Data-HashMap-Lazy.html#t%3aHashMap). This is going to be substantially faster but pretty much just as simple since the interface of `HashMap` largely matches that of `Map`, so you probably want to go that way.

Now, sadly neither is *quite* as simple to use as `MemoCombinators`. That builds directly on `IntTrie`, which is specialised for offering a lazy / infinite / pure interface. Both `Map` and particularly `HashMap`, in contrast, can be used very well for impure memoisation, but are not inherently able to do it purely. You [may throw in some `UnsafePerformIO`](http://augustss.blogspot.de/2011/04/ugly-memoization-heres-problem-that-i.html) (uh oh), or just do it openly in the `IO` monad (yuk!). Or use `StableMemo`.

But it's actually easy and safe if you already know which values it's going to be, at least most of the calls, *at compile-time*. Then you can just fill a local hash map with those values in the beginning, and at each call look up if it's there and otherwise simply call the expensive function directly:

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Lazy as HM

type X = Double  -- could really be anything else

notThatSlow :: Double -> X
notThatSlow = \v -> case HM.lookup v memo of
                 Just x  -> x
                 Nothing -> slow v
 where memo = HM.fromList [ (v, x) | v<-expectedValues, let x = slow v ]
```